# panda select columns different frames

Tags: pandas

I have a bunch of csv files. Each csv file comes from a machine and the epoch time of each csv file is roughly the same.

I want to accomplish a few things:

1) plot the same column of each of the machines. So I can make a comparison between the machines of some metric on that machine. E.g. memory usage, or throughput.

2) 'sum' the column of each of the machines. E.g. if each machine is doing 100 context switches per second and I have 10 machines, I want to get these columns merged into a single '1000' context switches per 'cluster. This way I can get an easy overview of the total number of 'x' over all machines.

3) When I run multiple benchmarks, the epoch time of the data can't be compared. So what is the easiest way to change the offset? Should I play with the index column (e.g. subtract the offset of each of the column values). I'm not too crazy about that because if I modify the index values, I'm loosing data.

I have the first one up and running, but I'm having some serious problems with the labels (so I don't get the see any labels).

I also had the last one up and running, by subtracting the start value of each of the tests from each of the columns. So if they were e.g. [100,104, 120], after cleaning up they are reduced to [0,4,20]. But manually iterating over the content of a a column doesn't like they way Panda was meant to be used.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fr1 = pd.read_csv(
    "/home/pveentjer/PycharmProjects/report-generator/20KB/A2_W1-54.161.173.44-javaclient/performance-IntByteMapTest.csv")
fr2 = pd.read_csv(
    "/home/pveentjer/PycharmProjects/report-generator/20KB/A3_W1-54.167.139.194-javaclient/performance-IntByteMapTest.csv")

fr1["operations/second"].plot(label="foo")
fr2["operations/second"].plot(label="bar")

plt.savefig("foo.png")
```

Sample data machine 1

```
epoch,timestamp,operations,operations-delta,operations/second
1519997386.971,02/03/2018 13:29:46,11596,11596,11584.416
1519997387.971,02/03/2018 13:29:47,17935,6339,6339
1519997388.971,02/03/2018 13:29:48,24145,6210,6210
1519997389.972,02/03/2018 13:29:49,30356,6211,6204.795
1519997390.972,02/03/2018 13:29:50,36566,6210,6210
1519997391.972,02/03/2018 13:29:51,42777,6211,6211
1519997392.972,02/03/2018 13:29:52,48987,6210,6210
1519997393.972,02/03/2018 13:29:53,55199,6212,6212
1519997394.972,02/03/2018 13:29:54,61409,6210,6210
1519997395.972,02/03/2018 13:29:55,67620,6211,6211
1519997396.973,02/03/2018 13:29:56,73789,6169,6162.837
1519997397.973,02/03/2018 13:29:57,80038,6249,6249
1519997398.973,02/03/2018 13:29:58,86248,6210,6210
1519997399.973,02/03/2018 13:29:59,92454,6206,6206
1519997400.973,02/03/2018 13:30:00,98663,6209,6209
1519997401.973,02/03/2018 13:30:01,104870,6207,6207
1519997402.974,02/03/2018 13:30:02,111081,6211,6204.795
1519997403.974,02/03/2018 13:30:03,117283,6202,6202
1519997404.974,02/03/2018 13:30:04,123498,6215,6215
1519997405.974,02/03/2018 13:30:05,129705,6207,6207
1519997406.974,02/03/2018 13:30:06,135913,6208,6208
1519997407.974,02/03/2018 13:30:07,142091,6178,6178
1519997408.974,02/03/2018 13:30:08,148327,6236,6236
1519997409.975,02/03/2018 13:30:09,154536,6209,6202.797
1519997410.975,02/03/2018 13:30:10,160746,6210,6210
1519997411.975,02/03/2018 13:30:11,166956,6210,6210
1519997412.975,02/03/2018 13:30:12,173167,6211,6211
1519997413.975,02/03/2018 13:30:13,179376,6209,6209
1519997414.975,02/03/2018 13:30:14,185586,6210,6210
1519997415.975,02/03/2018 13:30:15,191796,6210,6210
1519997416.976,02/03/2018 13:30:16,198007,6211,6204.795
1519997417.976,02/03/2018 13:30:17,204217,6210,6210
1519997418.976,02/03/2018 13:30:18,210429,6212,6212
1519997419.976,02/03/2018 13:30:19,216636,6207,6207
1519997420.976,02/03/2018 13:30:20,222846,6210,6210
1519997421.976,02/03/2018 13:30:21,229057,6211,6211
1519997422.976,02/03/2018 13:30:22,235266,6209,6209
1519997423.977,02/03/2018 13:30:23,241476,6210,6203.796
1519997424.977,02/03/2018 13:30:24,247685,6209,6209
1519997425.977,02/03/2018 13:30:25,253893,6208,6208
1519997426.977,02/03/2018 13:30:26,260104,6211,6211
1519997427.977,02/03/2018 13:30:27,266312,6208,6208
1519997428.977,02/03/2018 13:30:28,272522,6210,6210
1519997429.977,02/03/2018 13:30:29,278732,6210,6210
1519997430.978,02/03/2018 13:30:30,284943,6211,6204.795
1519997431.978,02/03/2018 13:30:31,291154,6211,6211
1519997432.978,02/03/2018 13:30:32,297363,6209,6209
1519997433.978,02/03/2018 13:30:33,303574,6211,6211
1519997434.978,02/03/2018 13:30:34,309785,6211,6211
1519997435.978,02/03/2018 13:30:35,315996,6211,6211
1519997436.978,02/03/2018 13:30:36,322205,6209,6209
1519997437.979,02/03/2018 13:30:37,328418,6213,6206.793
1519997438.979,02/03/2018 13:30:38,334628,6210,6210
1519997439.979,02/03/2018 13:30:39,340839,6211,6211
1519997440.979,02/03/2018 13:30:40,347049,6210,6210
1519997441.979,02/03/2018 13:30:41,353260,6211,6211
1519997442.979,02/03/2018 13:30:42,359470,6210,6210
1519997443.979,02/03/2018 13:30:43,365681,6211,6211
1519997444.98,02/03/2018 13:30:44,371889,6208,6201.798
1519997445.98,02/03/2018 13:30:45,378099,6210,6210
1519997446.98,02/03/2018 13:30:46,384310,6211,6211
1519997447.98,02/03/2018 13:30:47,390518,6208,6208
1519997448.98,02/03/2018 13:30:48,396729,6211,6211
1519997449.98,02/03/2018 13:30:49,402939,6210,6210
1519997450.98,02/03/2018 13:30:50,409149,6210,6210
1519997451.98,02/03/2018 13:30:51,415358,6209,6209
1519997452.981,02/03/2018 13:30:52,421568,6210,6203.796
1519997453.981,02/03/2018 13:30:53,427779,6211,6211
1519997454.981,02/03/2018 13:30:54,433983,6204,6204
1519997455.981,02/03/2018 13:30:55,440196,6213,6213
1519997456.981,02/03/2018 13:30:56,446406,6210,6210
1519997457.981,02/03/2018 13:30:57,452615,6209,6209
1519997458.981,02/03/2018 13:30:58,458825,6210,6210
1519997459.982,02/03/2018 13:30:59,465036,6211,6204.795
1519997460.982,02/03/2018 13:31:00,471247,6211,6211
1519997461.982,02/03/2018 13:31:01,477457,6210,6210
1519997462.982,02/03/2018 13:31:02,483668,6211,6211
1519997463.982,02/03/2018 13:31:03,489876,6208,6208
1519997464.982,02/03/2018 13:31:04,496085,6209,6209
1519997465.982,02/03/2018 13:31:05,502293,6208,6208
1519997466.983,02/03/2018 13:31:06,508503,6210,6203.796
1519997467.983,02/03/2018 13:31:07,514713,6210,6210
1519997468.983,02/03/2018 13:31:08,520925,6212,6212
1519997469.983,02/03/2018 13:31:09,527135,6210,6210
1519997470.983,02/03/2018 13:31:10,533344,6209,6209
1519997471.983,02/03/2018 13:31:11,539554,6210,6210
1519997472.983,02/03/2018 13:31:12,545764,6210,6210
1519997473.984,02/03/2018 13:31:13,551974,6210,6203.796
1519997474.984,02/03/2018 13:31:14,558184,6210,6210
1519997475.984,02/03/2018 13:31:15,564394,6210,6210
1519997476.984,02/03/2018 13:31:16,570604,6210,6210
1519997477.984,02/03/2018 13:31:17,576814,6210,6210
1519997478.984,02/03/2018 13:31:18,583024,6210,6210
1519997479.984,02/03/2018 13:31:19,589235,6211,6211
1519997480.985,02/03/2018 13:31:20,595445,6210,6203.796
1519997481.985,02/03/2018 13:31:21,601657,6212,6212
1519997482.985,02/03/2018 13:31:22,607869,6212,6212
1519997483.985,02/03/2018 13:31:23,614081,6212,6212
1519997484.985,02/03/2018 13:31:24,620293,6212,6212
1519997485.985,02/03/2018 13:31:25,626504,6211,6211
1519997486.985,02/03/2018 13:31:26,632715,6211,6211
1519997487.986,02/03/2018 13:31:27,638903,6188,6181.818
1519997488.986,02/03/2018 13:31:28,645133,6230,6230
1519997489.986,02/03/2018 13:31:29,651343,6210,6210
1519997490.986,02/03/2018 13:31:30,657553,6210,6210
1519997491.986,02/03/2018 13:31:31,663763,6210,6210
1519997492.986,02/03/2018 13:31:32,669973,6210,6210
1519997493.987,02/03/2018 13:31:33,676183,6210,6203.796
1519997494.987,02/03/2018 13:31:34,682394,6211,6211
1519997495.987,02/03/2018 13:31:35,688604,6210,6210
1519997496.987,02/03/2018 13:31:36,694815,6211,6211
1519997497.987,02/03/2018 13:31:37,701026,6211,6211
1519997498.987,02/03/2018 13:31:38,707224,6198,6198
1519997499.987,02/03/2018 13:31:39,713442,6218,6218
1519997500.988,02/03/2018 13:31:40,719624,6182,6175.824
1519997501.988,02/03/2018 13:31:41,725861,6237,6237
1519997502.988,02/03/2018 13:31:42,732068,6207,6207
1519997503.988,02/03/2018 13:31:43,738279,6211,6211
1519997504.988,02/03/2018 13:31:44,744490,6211,6211
1519997505.988,02/03/2018 13:31:45,750698,6208,6208
```

Sample data machine 2

```
epoch,timestamp,operations,operations-delta,operations/second
1519997387.035,02/03/2018 13:29:47,11600,11600,11576.846
1519997388.035,02/03/2018 13:29:48,17811,6211,6211
1519997389.035,02/03/2018 13:29:49,24023,6212,6212
1519997390.035,02/03/2018 13:29:50,30235,6212,6212
1519997391.035,02/03/2018 13:29:51,36448,6213,6213
1519997392.035,02/03/2018 13:29:52,42659,6211,6211
1519997393.036,02/03/2018 13:29:53,48873,6214,6207.792
1519997394.036,02/03/2018 13:29:54,55083,6210,6210
1519997395.036,02/03/2018 13:29:55,61295,6212,6212
1519997396.036,02/03/2018 13:29:56,67507,6212,6212
1519997397.036,02/03/2018 13:29:57,73716,6209,6209
1519997398.036,02/03/2018 13:29:58,79928,6212,6212
1519997399.037,02/03/2018 13:29:59,86140,6212,6205.794
1519997400.037,02/03/2018 13:30:00,92348,6208,6208
1519997401.037,02/03/2018 13:30:01,98560,6212,6212
1519997402.037,02/03/2018 13:30:02,104768,6208,6208
1519997403.037,02/03/2018 13:30:03,110917,6149,6149
1519997404.037,02/03/2018 13:30:04,117187,6270,6270
1519997405.037,02/03/2018 13:30:05,123397,6210,6210
1519997406.038,02/03/2018 13:30:06,129606,6209,6202.797
1519997407.038,02/03/2018 13:30:07,135817,6211,6211
1519997408.038,02/03/2018 13:30:08,142026,6209,6209
1519997409.038,02/03/2018 13:30:09,148226,6200,6200
1519997410.038,02/03/2018 13:30:10,154445,6219,6219
1519997411.038,02/03/2018 13:30:11,160656,6211,6211
1519997412.038,02/03/2018 13:30:12,166869,6213,6213
1519997413.039,02/03/2018 13:30:13,173083,6214,6207.792
1519997414.039,02/03/2018 13:30:14,179296,6213,6213
1519997415.039,02/03/2018 13:30:15,185509,6213,6213
1519997416.039,02/03/2018 13:30:16,191721,6212,6212
1519997417.039,02/03/2018 13:30:17,197935,6214,6214
1519997418.039,02/03/2018 13:30:18,204147,6212,6212
1519997419.039,02/03/2018 13:30:19,210359,6212,6212
1519997420.04,02/03/2018 13:30:20,216569,6210,6203.796
1519997421.04,02/03/2018 13:30:21,222780,6211,6211
1519997422.04,02/03/2018 13:30:22,228993,6213,6213
1519997423.04,02/03/2018 13:30:23,235204,6211,6211
1519997424.04,02/03/2018 13:30:24,241415,6211,6211
1519997425.04,02/03/2018 13:30:25,247628,6213,6213
1519997426.04,02/03/2018 13:30:26,253841,6213,6213
1519997427.041,02/03/2018 13:30:27,260053,6212,6205.794
1519997428.041,02/03/2018 13:30:28,266265,6212,6212
1519997429.041,02/03/2018 13:30:29,272475,6210,6210
1519997430.041,02/03/2018 13:30:30,278686,6211,6211
1519997431.041,02/03/2018 13:30:31,284900,6214,6214
1519997432.041,02/03/2018 13:30:32,291112,6212,6212
1519997433.041,02/03/2018 13:30:33,297324,6212,6212
1519997434.042,02/03/2018 13:30:34,303535,6211,6204.795
1519997435.042,02/03/2018 13:30:35,309749,6214,6214
1519997436.042,02/03/2018 13:30:36,315960,6211,6211
1519997437.042,02/03/2018 13:30:37,322172,6212,6212
1519997438.042,02/03/2018 13:30:38,328385,6213,6213
1519997439.042,02/03/2018 13:30:39,334597,6212,6212
1519997440.042,02/03/2018 13:30:40,340809,6212,6212
1519997441.043,02/03/2018 13:30:41,347002,6193,6186.813
1519997442.043,02/03/2018 13:30:42,353233,6231,6231
1519997443.043,02/03/2018 13:30:43,359445,6212,6212
1519997444.043,02/03/2018 13:30:44,365657,6212,6212
1519997445.043,02/03/2018 13:30:45,371869,6212,6212
1519997446.043,02/03/2018 13:30:46,378081,6212,6212
1519997447.043,02/03/2018 13:30:47,384294,6213,6213
1519997448.044,02/03/2018 13:30:48,390506,6212,6205.794
1519997449.044,02/03/2018 13:30:49,396719,6213,6213
1519997450.044,02/03/2018 13:30:50,402932,6213,6213
1519997451.044,02/03/2018 13:30:51,409144,6212,6212
1519997452.044,02/03/2018 13:30:52,415355,6211,6211
1519997453.044,02/03/2018 13:30:53,421573,6218,6218
1519997454.044,02/03/2018 13:30:54,427784,6211,6211
1519997455.045,02/03/2018 13:30:55,433996,6212,6205.794
1519997456.045,02/03/2018 13:30:56,440208,6212,6212
1519997457.045,02/03/2018 13:30:57,446417,6209,6209
1519997458.045,02/03/2018 13:30:58,452629,6212,6212
1519997459.045,02/03/2018 13:30:59,458840,6211,6211
1519997460.045,02/03/2018 13:31:00,465052,6212,6212
1519997461.045,02/03/2018 13:31:01,471262,6210,6210
1519997462.046,02/03/2018 13:31:02,477470,6208,6201.798
1519997463.046,02/03/2018 13:31:03,483656,6186,6186
1519997464.046,02/03/2018 13:31:04,489892,6236,6236
1519997465.046,02/03/2018 13:31:05,496106,6214,6214
1519997466.046,02/03/2018 13:31:06,502315,6209,6209
1519997467.046,02/03/2018 13:31:07,508528,6213,6213
1519997468.046,02/03/2018 13:31:08,514740,6212,6212
1519997469.047,02/03/2018 13:31:09,520951,6211,6204.795
1519997470.047,02/03/2018 13:31:10,527165,6214,6214
1519997471.047,02/03/2018 13:31:11,533376,6211,6211
1519997472.047,02/03/2018 13:31:12,539589,6213,6213
1519997473.047,02/03/2018 13:31:13,545801,6212,6212
1519997474.047,02/03/2018 13:31:14,552013,6212,6212
1519997475.048,02/03/2018 13:31:15,558225,6212,6205.794
1519997476.048,02/03/2018 13:31:16,564436,6211,6211
1519997477.048,02/03/2018 13:31:17,570650,6214,6214
1519997478.048,02/03/2018 13:31:18,576862,6212,6212
1519997479.048,02/03/2018 13:31:19,583073,6211,6211
1519997480.048,02/03/2018 13:31:20,589287,6214,6214
1519997481.048,02/03/2018 13:31:21,595499,6212,6212
1519997482.049,02/03/2018 13:31:22,601711,6212,6205.794
1519997483.049,02/03/2018 13:31:23,607923,6212,6212
1519997484.049,02/03/2018 13:31:24,614136,6213,6213
1519997485.049,02/03/2018 13:31:25,620350,6214,6214
1519997486.049,02/03/2018 13:31:26,626562,6212,6212
1519997487.049,02/03/2018 13:31:27,632775,6213,6213
1519997488.049,02/03/2018 13:31:28,638951,6176,6176
1519997489.05,02/03/2018 13:31:29,645195,6244,6237.762
1519997490.05,02/03/2018 13:31:30,651408,6213,6213
1519997491.05,02/03/2018 13:31:31,657619,6211,6211
1519997492.05,02/03/2018 13:31:32,663831,6212,6212
1519997493.05,02/03/2018 13:31:33,670044,6213,6213
1519997494.05,02/03/2018 13:31:34,676256,6212,6212
1519997495.05,02/03/2018 13:31:35,682469,6213,6213
1519997496.051,02/03/2018 13:31:36,688679,6210,6203.796
1519997497.051,02/03/2018 13:31:37,694892,6213,6213
1519997498.051,02/03/2018 13:31:38,701103,6211,6211
1519997499.051,02/03/2018 13:31:39,707317,6214,6214
1519997500.051,02/03/2018 13:31:40,713485,6168,6168
1519997501.051,02/03/2018 13:31:41,719733,6248,6248
1519997502.051,02/03/2018 13:31:42,725945,6212,6212
1519997503.052,02/03/2018 13:31:43,732152,6207,6200.799
1519997504.052,02/03/2018 13:31:44,738363,6211,6211
1519997505.052,02/03/2018 13:31:45,744574,6211,6211
1519997506.052,02/03/2018 13:31:46,750781,6207,6207
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data of both csv files? What you really want is to be able to match indexes of both files and merge them into one dataframe with columns for each machine observation.

Comment: I have added some sample data.

Yes. I want to merge them. Ideally I want to merge them based on position; each machine will output at a fixed rate. So they don't really need to be merged on time of the clocks are not perfectly in sync. In that case any of the clocks selected is fine.

Answer (score 1):

By merging on position you mean on row position? Because in that case you could just concatenate them as such:

`df = pd.concat([fr1, fr2], axis=1)`

Not sure if I understand your sum question properly, but because you have all data in one frame you could now add columns together as such:

`df['sum_ops'] = df['operations'] + df['operations2']`

(I renamed the headers for the second csv so that there are no columns with the same name)

For plotting it might be nice to have a `DatetimeIndex`, even though not all times line up perfectly. Just choose the best timestamp column, convert it to datetime and assign it to the index:

`df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']))`

Next to make for better plotting I would drop all `epoch` and `timestamp` columns:

`del df['epoch']` etc.

Comment: Adding the columns works great. So that is 1 problem solved.

Do you know how I can plot the same column of different frames + I get a label per column? So plotting multiple columns is no issue; only I don't get a label per 'line'

Comment: Run `plt.legend()` before `plt.savefig()`

Comment: The legend is visible, the problem is that since I'm comparing the same columns of different frames, the same name is printed multiple time.

Is there a better way than renaming the column to get the appropriate name in there?

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to temporary select an index (e.g. epoch time), do some truncation (needed to remove data for warmup and cooldown) and then restore the original index?